# cshrc set path different with setenv PATH

Tags: shell, csh

are there any diffrence between set path and setenv PATH in cshrc ?

I know that the uppercase of PATH is the environment variable
and control the tool's path

but in my **.cshrc** file, there is a line

```
"set path = 
.  \
./bin \
/usr/sbin \
/sbin \
/usr/dt/bin \
......."
```

and there contains some path of my tool, and i comment that line
then i create a new terminal, it shows command not found
but the path is define in $PATH(comment in the path variable)

so the lowercase path can effect the environment variable $PATH??

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

```
so the lowercase `$path` can effect the environment variable `$PATH`?
```

The answer is **YES**.

Now, to quote from [[ here ]](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix8.html)

> In general, environment and shell variables that have the same name
>   are distinct and independent, except for
>   possibly having the same initial values. 
> There are, however,
>   **exceptions**....
>  PATH and
>   path specify directories to search for commands and programs. Both
>   variables always represent the same directory list, and altering
>   either automatically causes the other to be changed.

So, when you comment out `path` in `.rc` file, you are effectively emptying it I guess.